# XQuery, how to know the number of terms in common between two sets of distinctive-terms

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to know the number of terms in common between two sets of `distinctive-terms` extracted from two paragraphs. I've extracted the `distinctive-terms` from each paragraph using `distinctive-terms` function in `XQuery`. Now I want to know the number of terms in common between the two sets of `distinctive-terms`. Is there a function to do so?

**NOTE**: I've attached a screen shot of a sample of the distinctive terms of a paragraph.
[image: sample of the distinctive terms]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do something like `$left-terms[. = $right-terms]` to get the intersect, but I wouldn't be surprised if you would want to run this over multiple documents. In that case I'd suggest tagging distinctive terms inline, or adding the terms to the content, indexing that, and using a facet or the low-level `cts:values` to get frequency-based top-terms..

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to know the "intersection set" between two sets.  This can easily be accomplished in MarkLogic using `map:map` objects.

You can get a lot of information here: http://www.xquerycoder.com/2014/04/set-theory-map-operators.html

I'll give a small example here:

```
(: Two sequences :)
let $strings1 := ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
let $strings2 := ("a","d","p","q")

(: Put them in maps :)
let $map1 := map:new($strings1 ! map:entry(., "1"))
let $map2 := map:new($strings2 ! map:entry(., "1"))

(: Take the intersection, get the keys from it :)
return for $key in map:keys($map1 * $map2)
  return $key
```

I will note that the reason I would use map operators rather than something such as `$items1[. eq $items2]` is because I find that map operators are extremely fast when dealing with large amounts of data.  Plus, there is some flexibility that I appreciate with different types of set operations.

Comment: In the created two maps if the value of each key is different then how to take common keys from two maps?
for example:
map1 = [a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]
map2 = [a = 2, b = 3, c = 4, d = 5]

In the above case the common keys will be - a,b,c 
in the above example assume both maps are of map:map() type (just for the example taking it as key pair)